# Convergence of infinite product and its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I wanted to find $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}+...)$ and ended up simplifying it as
$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2-1}$. Now the partial product is $\frac{2n}{n+1}$ it converges and it's limit is 2.. am I correct? Kindly share your views

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @5xum I Changed my question Infact I think I solved it... Now my question is am I correct... so kindly consider removing the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check your results, in order to verify your answer.

- First, we can show that
  $$1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}+\cdots =\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}.$$
- If $n\geqslant 1$, we can show that
  $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^k=\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}$$
- Then,
  $$\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^6}+\cdots  \right)=\prod_{n=2 }^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^k=\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)$$
- If you showed that for all $N\in\mathbf{N}$ we can write
  $$\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)=\frac{2N}{N+1},$$
  (this is indeed true, but you should have to justify it; a way it is using partial fraction), then taking $N\to +\infty$ both sides we find
  $$\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\left(\frac{2N}{N+1}\right)=2$$
  (it follows directly by definition) and then we get the answer $2$ as you said.

Comment: Yes I did the same way as you did, evaluated the partial products and there happened a telescopic cancellation (Kind of), then it became easy.. thank you for elaborate explanation